# How can I pipeline specific line of file as a command in linux command line?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to execute specific line of text file in bash. I was wondering is it possible to do that without copying that line in a new file and executing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @kev's answer (without piping to a new `bash`): Take his script source

#### `script.sh`

```
echo hello
echo world
echo foo
echo bar
```

and execute a certain line inside a `$(...)`:

#### command:

```
$(sed -n '3p' script.sh)
```

It will print `foo` in <strike>bash</strike> your current shell.

Comment: @ormaaj: I agree with you in discouraging such a concept. On the other hand it comes handy when following instructions from a simple diary (log) file.

Comment: I agree, this is exactly why am I using it.

Comment: @fheub: This isn't a good answer because the argument list is built by word-splitting, with pathname expansion enabled. This will fail in all but simple cases. Always quote command substitutions. kev's answer is ok. Mine works in either a child process or the current environment because of the `eval` (and uses properly escaped input). If you have GNU sed available, a shell command can be executed in pure sed using the `e` function: `sed -n $'3{e\np;q}' file`

Comment: @ormaaj: Touché! But Vladimir seems to be looking for a KISS-solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### `script.sh`

```
echo hello
echo world
echo foo
echo bar
```

#### command:

```
sed -n '3p' script.sh | bash
```

It will print `foo`

Comment: I think you should pipe to `bash` as Vladimir wants to execute the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could but probably shouldn't. Create a library containing functions and source it. This is a very unusual requirement. Bash has actual means of control flow - there's no need to grab strings of code out of files to execute. This can be dangerous.

Here's a "toy" example, not for production use...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

# evalLine filepath line-number
evalLine() {
    [[ -f $1 && $2 == +([[:digit:]]) ]] || return 1
    local x
    # This subtraction compensates for a bug that's since been fixed in 4.2.35 
    mapfile -ts $(($2 - 1)) -n 1 x &&
    ${x:+eval "$x"}
} <"$1"

evalLine /dev/stdin "$1" <<"EOF"
echo "line 1"
f() { echo "$1"; }; f "line 2"
var3='line 3' eval 'echo "$var3"'
EOF
```

**Late edit**: Note the comment regarding a bug in `mapfile`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a shell script, you could do that like in this example:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINE='less'
#...
LINE="$LINE myfile.txt"
# now we execute that:
$LINE
```

Another example includes capturing the output for further processing:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINE="grep foo bar.txt"
OUTPUT=$($LINE)
```

In the second example, the variable `$OUTPUT` then contains the results of the executed `grep` command.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not quite what you want, but could be useful to mention:

```
history -r script.sh
```

This reads each line of the script into your history list, from which you can execute any line using `bash`'s history expansion feature.

---

A few failed attempts at reading in just the line you want to execute:

```
# No command substitution; the argument is added literally
history -s $(sed -n '3p' script.sh)

# Can't seem to read from stdin or from a process substitution
sed -n '3p' script.sh | history -r -
sed -n '3p' script.sh | history -r /dev/stdin
history -r <( sed -n '3p' script.sh )
```